# TableView displaying content when designed in IB, but not displaying content when im writing programatically, what i was doing wrong

Tags: swift, uitableview

```
class AddTripExpense: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    //  @IBOutlet weak var storePicker: UITableView!

    var storePicker = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        storePicker.delegate = self
        storePicker.dataSource = self
        storePicker = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: storeNameTF.frame.origin.x + 3, y: storeNameTF.frame.origin.y + storeNameTF.frame.height + 3, width: storeNameTF.frame.width + 50, height: 150), style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
        view.addSubview(storePicker)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if (tableView == storePicker) {
            return savedStoresArray.count
        }
        return 15
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        if(tableView == storePicker) {
            // let typeOfExpenseCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "typeOfExpenseCell", for: indexPath)
            let storePickerCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "storePickerCell")
            storePickerCell.textLabel?.text = savedStoresArray[indexPath.row]

            return storePickerCell
        }

        return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of setting the `delegate` and `datasource` should be as below,

```
storePicker = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: storeNameTF.frame.origin.x + 3, y: storeNameTF.frame.origin.y + storeNameTF.frame.height + 3, width: storeNameTF.frame.width + 50, height: 150), style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
storePicker.delegate = self
storePicker.dataSource = self
view.addSubview(storePicker)
```

Currently you are assigning `delegate` and `dataSource` to `storePicker` instance that is getting re-assigned with this line

```
storePicker = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: storeNameTF.frame.origin.x + 3, y: storeNameTF.frame.origin.y + storeNameTF.frame.height + 3, width: storeNameTF.frame.width + 50, height: 150), style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
```

Re-assigning `storePicker` to a new `UITableView` instance sets `delegate` and `datasource` to `nil` so you need to set them again as above.

Comment: Also you might need to call `storePicker.reloadData()` after `view.addSubview(storePicker)` or after setting the dataSource i.e, `savedStoresArray`

Comment: The order of setting the delegate and datasource should be as below,

storePicker = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: storeNameTF.frame.origin.x + 3, y: storeNameTF.frame.origin.y + storeNameTF.frame.height + 3, width: storeNameTF.frame.width + 50, height: 150), style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
storePicker.delegate = self
storePicker.dataSource = self
view.addSubview(storePicker) Its Working Dude, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set the `delegate` and `dataSource` after initialization of `UITableView`

```
    storePicker = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: storeNameTF.frame.origin.x + 3, y: storeNameTF.frame.origin.y + storeNameTF.frame.height + 3, width: storeNameTF.frame.width + 50, height: 150), style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
    storePicker.delegate = self
    storePicker.dataSource = self
    view.addSubview(storePicker)
    storePicker.reloadData()
```